# Date shell command in hive script

Tags: hive

I would like to run date command in hive script. It being a shell command, I tried using a preceding '!'. Tried the following:

```
hive (default)> !date --date="6 months ago";
date: extra operand `ago"'
Try `date --help' for more information.
Command failed with exit code = 1
```

Comment: Yeah. The hive parser does not honor the quotes when parsing the command, so it tries to execute `date` with 3 args i.e. `--date="6` then `months` then `ago"`. You have no workaround. Blank space cannot be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @samson in comment hive does not parse the command `--date="6 months ago";`. You can use below workaround.

```
select add_months(current_date(),-6);
```